# Ansible raw module: compare local time with target nodes time

Tags: time, lazy-evaluation, ansible, delayed-execution

All my target machine are actually android and does not have python

So I wanna know each machine's time compared to my local time.

```
ansible all -m raw -a "echo $(date +%s); date +%s"
```

Does not work, since `$(date +%s)` is evaluated since beginning of the execution, and there are so many nodes that executes much later.

Is there a way to delay evaluation?

Comment: perhaps a more appropriate solution is for each of your devices to run `ntp` or similar service and they'll make sure they are clock-sync on their own?

Comment: @mxx It's PITA to install extra tools on there Android nodes. The entire OS is on a loop device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO using simple ssh is easier than ansible for this is purpose.

If you do want to continue using ansible check out [the `--forks|-f` option](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_adhoc.html#parallelism-and-shell-commands) like if you have 100 androids to talk to then:

```
ansible all -f 100 -m raw -a "echo $(date +%s); date +%s"
```

or do the good old ssh:

```
for h in `ansible all -i inventory.ini --list-hosts`; do d=`date +%s`; ssh $h "echo \$HOSTNAME - $(date +%s) - $d" & done
```

Comment: Using "good old ssh" via something like [parallel ssh](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) would also give you the sort of parallelization that Ansible provides without the additional overhead.

Comment: @BruceP nice, didn't know abt `pssh`.. now I can replace a bunch of my aliases looping over lists of hosts.. :-)